# MongooseJS - update (not working), findByIdAndUpdate (working) - why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Using Mongoose JS, and trying to update a field in my MongoDB datastore; I'm struggling to understand why this works:

```
MyModel
    .findByIdAndUpdate( req.params.id, field: someValue )
    .exec () -> 
         ...callback
```

But the following *don't* work? i.e. using a find / where + update.

```
MyModel
    .findOne( _id: req.params.id )
    .update( field: someValue )
    .exec () ->
         ...callback
```

OR

```
MyModel
    .where( _id: req.params.id )
    .update( field: someValue )
    .exec () ->
         ...callback
```

Really got me scratching my head!

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?  Nothing happens?  It sets the wrong value?  What behavior do you see?

Comment: You should check the callback's first parameter for an error and include that information.

Comment: Hey guys [sorry late replies, no email notify!] --- @juanpaco: both parameters from .exec (error, object) are null on console.log -- I've double checked the id is correct. And it works in the findByIdAndUpdate format. Seems there's something wrong about the query structure that just doesn't work. Can't work out what it is though....

Comment: I believe `.exec` works only with models with query condition, ie with find methods and not with update or create.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused due to mongoose findOne() return the document but you can not operate on it you need to convert it in javascript object and then pass it to update function.

But you can use below method to update the documents

you can refer mongoose documentation as well.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

```
Model.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
   if (err) { return err;}
  doc.name = 'jason bourne';
  doc.save(callback);
});
```